# What is the flow of: Implementing VueJS into an existing Laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8

Hi im not an advanced coder just a hobbyist with 1% javascript experience, only laravel and rubyrails.

I have build a admin dashboard with crud and everything in 100% laravel-8...
Now i want to replace all the crud tables i got with Vue.js.
Unfortunately i have found it to be quite confusing to understand. I see a lot of people be replacing there blade view with vue components and routes too. Can someone explain me the flow of the whole process of replacing and folder managing in vue?

If u know a good site that would be helpful too.
Please do not send orginal Vue documentation site, thank u.

Comment: You will learn this by following Vue tutorials. The relationship between Vue and Laravel is:  Vue is for the views and Laravel provides data through xhr-calls from Vue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating another project for the client side, for example, **VueCli or NuxtJs**. And use the Laravel project as a RestFull API that provides all the data needed in the client side.

That will provide you **much more scalability**, rather than having it all together in the Laravel project.